# Copying constantly changing directory

Tags: command-line, cron, copy

I am trying to copy files from a directory that is in constant use by a security cam program. To archive these .jpg files to another HD, I first need to copy them.  The problem is, the directory is being filled as the copying proceeds at the rate of about 10 .jpgs per second.  I have the option of stopping the program, do the copy then start it again which is not what I want to do for many reasons.  Or I could do the find/mtime approach. I have tried the following:

```
find /var/cache/zm/events/* -mmin +5 -exec cp -r {} /media/events_cache/ \;
```

Which under normal circumstances would work.  But it seems the directories are also changing their timestamps and branch off in different directions so it never comes out logically and for some reason each directory is very deep like /var/cache/zm/events/../../../../../../../001.jpg x 3000.  All I want to do is copy the files and directories via cron with a simple command line if possible.  With the directories constantly changing, is there are way to make this copy without stopping the program?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rsync should be a better option in this case but you will need to try it out. Try setting it up at off peak hours when the traffic is not that high.

Another option would be setting up the directory on a volume which uses say mirroring or RAID 5 ; this way you do not have to worry about losing data (if that indeed is your concern).

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  It's a simple rotation backup I am trying to do without disturbing the nature of the original events of the cam server.  The cam server program doesn't always like you messing with it's file locations.  So, I'm copying the files outright first, then tar them with the day's date into another directory, remove the copied files, and finally removing the tar backups when they're 3 weeks old.  It's all works fine except for the copying part which has to copy the files while the directory is still being filled.

Comment: In that case, take a look at rsync ; it should work better than cp

Comment: Will do, I'll take a look..  If rsync will copy the files while the dir is in motion, that will be the answer.  Thanks